# Can Boost::asio::post can interrupt the running thread?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14, boost-asio

I am new to Boost::asio and I am currently looking at io_context.
I have a question regarding the function io_context::post
Posting on thread can preempt what's running on that thread currently ?
because in the documentation i have seen :
Deprecated: Use post.) Request the io_context to invoke the given handler and return immediately.
I'm expecting that post will be added to the event queue, and will only be considered to run again when control is passed back to the event loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it cannot interrupt the running thread(s) associated with the `io_context`. `post()` enqueues the task to the `io_context` which will execute it eventually. The "return immediately" is meant in terms of the `post()` call itself, not the task. So the `post()` function returns immediately without blocking, but the task is scheduled for later execution.

Comment: The same behavior should be with main tread also ?
I mean there is no difference between post to main thread and a non main thread

Comment: Asio does not distinguish between a *main thread* and *non-main threads*. There are threads that are used to run the `io_context` and will work on the task queue and there might be others. Asio never interrupts any thread.

Comment: More specifically, you cannot post to a thread. You post to an executor, which usually ends up queuing to an internal handler queue inside an execution context. One or more threads may be polling that execution context and the executor can impose additional scheduling restrictions.